# String Manipulation in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, string

I have been out of touch with programming for a while. I have some strings I want to format. They look like this:

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('4') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT1
,SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('3') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT2
,SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('2') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT3
,SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('1') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT4
,SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('0') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT5
```

I want to take this and change it to

```
,CNT1 = SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('4') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
,CNT2 = SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('3') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
,CNT3 = SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('2') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
,CNT4 = SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('1') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
,CNT5 = SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('0') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

right now I have a `multiline textbox` that I paste the strings in. I want to click a button and have it formatted into a second textbox.

This is what I've tried so far. but I am not sure what string functions to use format it the way i want.

```
            List<String> Items = new List<string>();
            string frTxt;
            foreach (string lne in txtM.Lines)
            {
                frTxt = "";
                frTxt = lne;

            }
```

where `txtM` is the multiline textbox. If I do `Console.WriteLine(lne);` in the loop, it loops through successfully.

Comment: You could use a regex. What have you tried, so far?

Comment: What precisely doesn't work at this point?  Are your strings being constructed correctly, and if they're not, how are they not?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Did you at least look at the [String documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the format is always

> ,<text_1> as <text_2>

This the following will transform it to:

> ,<text_2> = <text_1>

```
txtM.Lines = txtM.Lines.Select(l => Regex.Replace(l, ",(.+) as (.+?)$", ",$2 = $1")).ToArray();
```

Explanation of regex:

- The "," and " as " match those exact strings
- "(.+)" greedy-matches at least one character, and captures it as the first group
- "(.+?)" non-greedy-matches at least one character and captures it as the second group
- "$" matches the end of the line

As a result of combining the greedy and non-greedy matching, we force the " as ..." to be the last occurrence (so if the string happens to contain " as " somewhere in it, that won't matter). By adding the "$" we ensure that the second capture takes everything to the end of the line (otherwise as it's a non-greedy match it would match just the first character after " as ", which isn't what we want).

The replacement simply constructs the new string using the two groups captured by the regex, adding the "=". We also manually add back the "," at the beginning because our regex matches on it and so it will be replaced by the replacement string. (This can be overcome but would probably make the regex more complex).

Comment: this is perfect. can you explain how the regex pattern worked?

Comment: @masfenix Added a description in the answer.

Comment: thankyou. i know I can google this but what is the difference between greedy and non-greedy

Comment: "Greedy" matches as much of the input as possible to make the regex match, conversely "non-greedy" matches as little of the input as possible.

Answer (score 1):

well, if it's just the beginning and end there, you can do

```
myString.Replace(",", ",CNT1 = ").Replace(" as CNT1", "");
```

There are a lot of ways to do this with the built in `string` methods

[Check out the String documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)

Here's a fully functional and tested code snipit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] strArr = 
            {
            ",SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('4') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT1",
            ",SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('3') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT2",
            ",SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('2') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT3",
            ",SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('1') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT4",
            ",SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] IN('0') AND Program = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CNT5",
            };

            //intellisence didn't like assignment in the foreach loop
            for(int i=0; i<strArr.Length; i++)
            {
                string cnt = Regex.Match(strArr[i], @"CNT\d+$").Value;
                strArr[i] = strArr[i].Replace(",", String.Format(",{0} = ",cnt)).Replace(String.Format(" as {0}", cnt), "");
            }

            foreach(string str in strArr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. You probably want to show how to construct both search and replace strings as from sample it looks like CNT1-CNT5m not just CNT1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) with regular expressions matching and [Regex language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc).

You want to use grouping constructs `(...)` to capture place where to insert substring and second one to capture substring to insert.

Comment: I am not sure what my pattern would be?

Answer (score 0):

This is very specific. Is your input string always going to have that format? In that case, you can use something like this:

```
        string s = textBox1.Text;
        var result = s.Split(',').ToList();
        result.ForEach(x =>
        {
            int removeAfter = x.LastIndexOf(" as CNT");
            string cntNum = x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("CNT"), x.Length - 1);
            x = string.Format(",{0} = {1}", cntNum, x.Substring(0, removeAfter));
        });
```

But I strongly suggest looking into using regular expressions to search and replace.

Comment: the "as" part changes. IE, the column names are different.

Comment: Iridium's code worked flawlessly. Just looking for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your are using a richTextbox with multines please seeexample how you can do it

```
private void FormatLinesInTextBox()
{
    int cnt = 1;
    foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
    {
        string cntNumber = cntNumber = "CNT" + cnt;
        richTextBox1.Lines[cnt - 1] = "," + cntNumber + line.Replace(cntNumber, string.Empty);
        cnt++;
    }
}
```